# What is covariate imbalance?

Tags: unbalanced-classes, predictor

> Covariate imbalance refers to an unequal distribution of independent
> variables (covariates) among different groups in a dataset.

Is the above definition correct? So, would the following be an example for covariate imbalance?

A study includes 12 individuals (neglecting that the sample is too small) to study how their age (the covariate) influences their risk of having a certain medical condition (the outcome). The dataset is divided into two groups: group A and group B.

Group A:
Age: 25, 27, 30, 32

Group B:
Age: 40, 42, 45, 48, 50, 52, 55, 60

Comment: I would say that this example is above all an example of a far too small sample size.  The sample size needed to estimate a simple correlation between two variables with decent precision is $n=300$.  Your sample is too small to either quantify balance or to do anything about imbalance.

Answer (score 1):

A covariate is is a variable that is not of direct interest, but may still nonetheless influence the outcome. In your example, since your interest is age, I would say that it is not a covariate. If Group A was all males, and Group B was all females, I would say that that is a covariate imbalance. Here's another interesting example that might help further explain it: http://blog.pmean.com/covariate-imbalance/

Comment: Another way to say it is that if you assume a specific age vs. Y relationship and you’re right, you can adjust for imbalance so that the imbalance only causes an inefficiency in the statistical estimates.